# Error deploying in production ONLY

Tags: feature, feature-activation, solution-deployment, feature-receiver

I have a SharePoint solution, consisted of 2 features. The first feature is consisted of 5 SharePoint 2010 workflows, and some web pages. The second one is empty and has a feature event receiver that is used to deploy SharePoint timer job. Both feature have the scope set to Site, the SharePoint project is strongly signed, and, generally, the solution package, consisted of those 2 features, can be deployed to the production without issues and generally everything works just fine.

Then I wanted to add a third feature. This feature is also empty and has its own feature event receiver which is in charge of deploying a list item event listener that is hooking up to a particular SharePoint list. I added this feature as the third one in the solution package and tried it out in the development environment and again, everything worked just fine.

Then, I tried deploying to the production. I got the error outcome on `Install-SPFeature` command. Next, I copy-pasted the code from this new feature event receiver to the feature event receiver of the second feature, removed the 3rd feature from the package and deployed to the production without any issues.

Why does the .WSP installation fails in the production in case it contains the 3rd feature?

### Notes:

Feature 1 manifest (working fine):

```
<Feature
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="System Workflows"
  Id="fb57907b-b90d-4e87-a923-f413dfbae199" Scope="Site">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="Workflow1\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Workflow2\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Workflow3\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Workflow4\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="Workflow5\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Feature 2 manifest (working fine):

```
<Feature
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="SP Timer Job"
  Id="fc9d855b-c388-4a51-a897-80d4c135e751" Scope="Site"
  ReceiverAssembly="MySharePoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=601ce3adcd2b4c27"
  ReceiverClass="MySharePoint.Features.Feature2.Feature2EventReceiver">
</Feature>
```

Feature 3 manifest (not working):

```
<Feature
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="List Item Event Listener"
  Id="31712f8d-449b-4f92-973f-faaf04517e8f" Scope="Site"
  ReceiverAssembly="MySharePoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=601ce3adcd2b4c27" 
  ReceiverClass="MySharePoint.Features.Feature3.Feature3EventReceiver">
</Feature>
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing at the end. Let me try to extract more information regarding the issue.......! You want to deploy only third feature in the production environment using the same solution pkg and skip the feature 1 and feature 2? You tried to copy paste the feature 3 code into feature 2 code and it didn't reflect any result in production?

Comment: No, I want to have all 3 features be part of one package. The problem is that installation of the package fails if it contains the 3rd feature. Everything works fine if it the package is consisted of the first two only.

Comment: What is the error message? You should include that in the question.

Comment: Agree with James. Please provide error details. I haven't heard any limitations like this in a solution package in SharePoint. Most probably its some other error and ULS logs will help to get that.